# SSL: Certificate does not match the name (Cloudflare)

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy, cloudflare

I'm running this docker along with this config to use cloudfare as a CDN to get better peering, mainly for Plex streaming.

https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/letsencrypt/

https://github.com/toomuchio/plex-nginx-reverseproxy

Everything was working fine until yesterday, when Chrome started giving this error:

```
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
Subject: sni220824.cloudflaressl.com
Issuer: COMODO ECC Domain Validation Secure Server CA 2
```

digicert.com says:

```
Common Name = sni220824.cloudflaressl.com
Subject Alternative Names = sni220824.cloudflaressl.com, *.aomenlanguifangyuleguibinting.com, *.attractivestrangers.com, *.avrost.cf, *.batrot.tk, *.bytes-os.com, *.cockheyt.nl, *.everythingfixixf.cf, *.fixkitty.tk, *.fixparties.gq, *.glenniest.com, *.hdwallpaperxd.com, *.ipricecat.press, *.planerost.cf, *.pmudlead.cf, *.protoncleaning.com.au, *.resnl.nl, *.rostspy.tk, *.rotplane.ga, *.shopzero.xyz, *.skillreview.com, *.uncuriosolugar.com, aomenlanguifangyuleguibinting.com, attractivestrangers.com, avrost.cf, batrot.tk, bytes-os.com, cockheyt.nl, everythingfixixf.cf, fixkitty.tk, fixparties.gq, glenniest.com, hdwallpaperxd.com, ipricecat.press, planerost.cf, pmudlead.cf, protoncleaning.com.au, resnl.nl, rostspy.tk, rotplane.ga, shopzero.xyz, skillreview.com, uncuriosolugar.com
Issuer = COMODO ECC Domain Validation Secure Server CA 2
Serial Number = 5B8918EF9DBF934021332123CC361CAF
SHA1 Thumbprint = 366A770128B3BD5ACEA675AB1D945DB8365DFDDA
Key Length = 256
Signature algorithm = SHA256 + ECC (excellent)
Secure Renegotiation: Supported
...

Certificate does not match name mydomain.org
```

"certbot certificates" in the docker console gives me:

```
root@b03e5d07fcdb:/$ certbot certificates
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Found the following certs:
  Certificate Name: mydomain.org
    Domains: mydomain.org plex.mydomain.org www.mydomain.org
    Expiry Date: 2017-09-21 00:07:00+00:00 (VALID: 89 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.org/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.org/privkey.pem
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Cloudflare SSL was set to Full, now I've set it to Full (Strict).

I'm kind of a newbie at this kind of thing so I'm a little lost and my google-fu hasn't helped.

EDIT: Aaand everything is working again. Why? I don't know.

My domain is listed on digicert and all reverse proxies and plex.mydomain.org just work.

Comment: what did you type into the address bar of chrome?

Comment: @JamesKPolk  
https: //plex.mydomain.org https: //mydomain.org/plexpy https: //mydomain.org/sonarr And all other reverse-proxy I'd already set up and were working.

Comment: mydomain.org doesn't match *any* of the domain names in the subject alternative name list, so chrome did the right thing when it returned an error.

Comment: Yeah lol. The thing I don't understand is why.

Answer (score 0):

This usually occurs when the SSL certificate is set for one domain and not the whole protocol of the website. e.g you have SSL activated, for example.com, not www.example.com there will be an error, what I will advise you to do is to contact your host to redirect the URL without the SSL to the one with SSL. Another way is to just buy the SSL certificate for all protocols of your domain www or non-www.

Comment: But I used letsencrypt for mydomain.org, plex.mydomain.org and www.mydomain.org. Shouldn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

Aaand everything is working again. Why? I don't know. I tried so many things last night and eventually gave up.

My domain is listed on digicert and all reverse proxies and plex.mydomain.org just work.